# Как проверить динамическая или же статическая веб страница с помощью python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, requests, web-scraping

У меня есть функция, которая принимает адрес веб страницы, html которой нужно достать. С первого взгляда задача проста, но мне нужно проверять динамическая или же статическая эта страница. В первом случае использовать селениум, в в другом библиотеку requests. Есть идеи, как реализовать такую проверку?

Comment: Такого строгого деления не существует, любая статическая страница может быть немножко динамической

Comment: Что значит динамическая страница? Та которая получает данные с сервера после загрузки асинхронно или та у которой DOM меняется безотносительно данных с сервера?

Answer (score 0):

В моем понимании статичный сайт - это сайт без javascript с DOM манипуляциями вовсе. Но мне как-то не попадаются такие (они есть). Думаю уместно перефразировать ваш вопрос на SPA и MPA.